# Angular - Search filter only works for the current page in Angular Pagination Search

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

In Angular-15, I am implementing search filter in my ngx-pagination with server side pagination. Precisely, I have a search text input. I have this code:

**JSON Response:**

```
{
      "data": {
        "pageItems": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
            "auditType": "string",
            "actionPerformed": "string",
            "actionPerformedTime": "2022-10-28T05:54:12.830Z"
          }
        ],
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "numberOfPages": 3,
        "totalRecord": 33
      },
      "successful": true,
      "message": "string",
      "statusCode": 0
}
```

**model:**

```
export interface IPageItem {
  id: string;
  auditType: string;
  actionPerformed: string;
  actionPerformedTime: Date;
}

export interface IData {
  pageItems: IPageItem[];
  pageSize: number;
  currentPage: number;
  numberOfPages: number;
  totalRecord: number;
}

export interface IAuditList {
  data: IData;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}
```

**service:**

```
getAllAuditsPagination(searchQuery?: string, pageNumber?: number,pageSize?: number): Observable<IAuditList[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('searchQuery', searchQuery?.toString() ?? '')
    .set('pageNumber', pageNumber?.toString() ?? '')
    .set('pageSize', pageSize?.toString() ?? '');
  return this.http.get<IAuditList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users/all-audits', { params: params });
}
```

**component.ts:**

```
  allAuditList: any[] = [];
  pageSize: number = 10;
  currentPage: number = 1;
  numberOfPages!: number;
  totalRecords: number = 0;
  pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];
  selectedName: string = '';
  searchQuery: string = '';

  handlePageChange(event: number): void {
    this.currentPage = event;
    this.loadAllAudits();
  }

  handlePageSizeChange(event: any): void {
    this.pageSize = event.target.value;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.loadAllAudits();
  }

onAuditSearch() {
  if (this.selectedName)
    this.allAuditList = this.allAuditList.filter(
      (row) =>
        row.auditType
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase())
    );
  else
    this.allAuditList = this.allAuditList;

  this.totalRecords = this.allAuditList.length;
  this.currentPage = 1;
}

  loadAllAudits() {
    this.auditService.getAllAuditsPagination(this.searchQuery, this.currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.allAuditList = res.data.pageItems;
        this.totalRecords = res.data.totalRecord;
        this.currentPage = res.data.currentPage;
        this.pageSize = res.data.pageSize;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }
```

**component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="auditType">Audit Type:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          autocomplete="off"
          class="form-control"
          id="auditType"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedName"
          (input)="onAuditSearch()"
          placeholder="auditType"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <tr
    *ngFor="
      let row of allAuditList
        | paginate
          : {
              itemsPerPage: pageSize,
              currentPage: currentPage,
              totalItems: totalRecords
            }
        | orderBy : order : reverse : caseInsensitive;
      let i = index
    "
  >

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <pagination-controls
      previousLabel="Prev"
      nextLabel="Next"
      [responsive]="true"
      (pageChange)="handlePageChange($event)"
    >
    </pagination-controls>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Items Per Page:
      <select (change)="handlePageSizeChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizes" [value]="size">
          {{ size }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I use text input field for search filter in the pagination.

But what I observe is that onAuditSearch() only works on the current page. For instance, If I navigate to page 2, the search filter will only work there.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you sould do this with pagination is filter data on the server side and return it to your application. Right now you are only getting a part of the data you want to filter because that is how pagination is supposed to work. For example, you have a total of 50 records, but you display 10 on the first page. The remaining 40 aren't being sent by the server so your application can not filter them.

You could either request all the data from your backend (what goes againt pagination principle) or implement filtering in the backend and get your filtered data with each input (I suggest using debounce to prevent sending too much requests to the backend).

Comment: I've already done filtering at the backend (ASP.NET Core Web API). That's why I have something like this in the Angular service.ts as shown in the code:    .set('searchQuery', searchQuery?.toString() ?? '').      But how do I translate this to the component.ts, and component.html of the pagination

Comment: @Ayobamilaye I don't understand why are you trying to filter your data in your component. The request you make to your backend should return already filtered data with no need for further filtering. Your ```onAuditSearch``` method should only make a new http request with your filtering string as parameter. It shouldn't filter your list.

Comment: How do I go about this?